# An equivalent condition for a cyclic von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be  a von Neumann algebra in $B(H)$. Assume that there exists a vector $\zeta\in H$ such that for any vector $h\in H$, one may find $\eta\in H$ and  operators $T,S$ in $M$ with

$\bullet$ $T\eta=\zeta$ and $\eta\in \ker T^{\perp}$.

$\bullet$ $S\eta=h$.

Q. Can we conclude that $M$ is a cyclic Von Neumann algebra?

Remark. This property is valid in any cyclic Von Neumann algebra (see [What is the idea behind the proof of the Theorem 7.2.1 in this book : Fundamental of the theory of operator algebras Vol II (Kadison and Ringros)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940782/what-is-the-idea-behind-the-proof-of-the-theorem-7-2-1-in-this-book-fundamenta)).